# Suitable AI algorithm for this classifying problem

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to classify the records based on dependent variable like below. I want to choose branch code as default branch which has higher revenue or higher number of customers compared to other branches in the same city.

I have used all the classification algorithms (Decision tree, MLPClassifier,ExtraTreesClassifier, RandomForestClassifier, etc.) But not able to get right solution.

My code:

```
data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

le = LabelEncoder()
for column in data.columns:
    if data[column].dtype == type(object):
        data[column] = le.fit_transform(data[column])

feature_cols = ['City','State','Branch Code','Revenue','Customers']
X = data.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,4]].values
y = data.iloc[:,5].values
clf = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=10)
clf.fit(X, y)
print('Default Branch',le.inverse_transform(clf.predict([le.fit_transform(['Chennai','TN','K9092',15000,3])])))
print("Score", clf.score(X,y))
```

I'm not able to get the right predictions so far. What I could be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: what is your target column? From your code it looks like you are trying to predict `Default Branch` while your `X` matrix also contains that column. You should be getting 100% accuracy.

Comment: You are right. Target column is Default branch. Im getting the 100% accuracy but the prediction is wrong always. I have added 100s of rows to improve the accuracy rate. But prediction check is always wrong

Comment: How do you mean you have 100% accuracy, but it’s always wrong?

Comment: I mean, the clf.score(X,y) shows 100% always. But I know it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Target column `y` is also present in your input matrix `X`. This allows the classifier to establish connection between the two columns and simply predict whatever is in the input.

For your program to actually learn relation between input variables and target variable, you need to remove the column `Default Branch` from the input matrix `X`.

As for the general performance of the classifier, I dont think any of the algorithms you have mentioned are suitable for this type of problem. Most machine learning algorithms do not retain the memory of previous inputs (there are some exceptions but they are still not suitable for this problem). If algorithm correctly guesses that branch with id `S2134` is correct output for its respective input, there is no way for it to memorize that and guess it for the next input.

The problem you have presented is not a good machine learning problem (or a machine learning problem at all)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have simplified my problem with 2 dependable columns(Revenue and Customers) using this sample. But I'd have various other parameters in my real world problem. I could achieve them today with too many if and else logic. But wanted to see if there is a good classification algorithm to solve the same.